# Why won't background CSS color stay on hover?

Tags: html, css

On this [dev site](http://ww2.joomlatest01.mms-dev.com/), if you hover of "BRANDS" in main menu, it brings up a dropdown. Hover over any of them and the background *blinks* red and then goes away.

I added background CSS to the "li" and "a" elements of the main menu like this...

```
.mega-dropdown-inner  ul.level1 li.open:hover{
background: red !important;
}
.mega-dropdown-inner  ul.level1 li a:hover{
background: red;
}
```

NOTE:  I don't think I even need the "a" styling, but just tried it in case it helps.

Any idea why the background color won't stay the whole time you are hovering?

Comment: That's because you have a `transition` on all of your `a`nchor tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of this rule

```
.t3-megamenu .mega-nav > li a:hover, .t3-megamenu .dropdown-menu .mega-nav > li a:hover, .t3-megamenu .mega-nav > li a:focus, .t3-megamenu .dropdown-menu .mega-nav > li a:focus {
   background-color: #002d5c !important; 
}
```

in your custom.css line 1031.

It is overriding your rule

Comment: @JeffNoel The answer is not suggesting using `important` merely stating that it is being used and that it is the source of the issue. Not sure if you gathered that or where just commenting overall.

Comment: @JeffNoel I don't disagree with you. I am not suggesting OP to use `!important` i just point out the problem

Comment: @laaposto I totally misunderstood your first comment, I thought *someone else* was not understanding your answer and I tried to explain to them, but it was you talking to downvoters. Sorry about that

Comment: I removed that code and it worked, so this was clearly right answer (not sure why it was downvoted), thank you!